# Tableau data layer to one state only

Tags: tableau-api

I'm looking to mask all of the detail in Tableau maps other than the state I'm filtered on.  The data layer can seemingly only be applied to all or nothing.  I'm unable to filter or limit to the dataset to which I'm working.  Seems simple, yet 30min of google search can't find answer.  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t believe that the map server can alter what it displays as a data layer based on the filters you choose in Tableau. The map server is a separate program that returns image tiles upon request. The map server doesn’t know about your filters on the client side - or even that the client app is called Tableau. It just knows that some client application asked for an image representing a map within a particular coordinate bounding box, with whatever style and data layer options that the client application passed.

That doesn’t mean you can’t accomplish your goal, just that you have to find a way to accomplish it on the Tableau side instead the map server side — unless you want to develop your own map server with that functionality, which would be an effort even with a tool like Mapbox.

You could

- Decide what “data layers” the map server is providing that you want to retain and at what level of detail, say Avg(Income) per County
- Go get that data, possibly from the census bureau
- Uncheck the box for your data layers in the Map Layers pane
- Use the data you downloaded above to color the map sections as desired
- Add other marks to represent additional info as needed using a dual-axis and possibly data blending

Then voila, your data layers will obey your filter. You just had to move where that info was drawn. Of course, you had to find the necessary data instead of relying on the whoever built the map server to do that, but that isn’t too tough.

To handle the Tableau side of things, especially assuming you want to combine the layer we’ve been discussing with other data on your map, you will need to learn about a few other Tableau concepts. So read up on dual-axis maps, level of detail and possibly data blending.

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this-Right click on the filter state and click show filter.Again right click on filter select "Multiple values(drop down) and then click the Customize and show apply button.Then choose the filter values and apply filter.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPSMi.png)